# Foreach внутри switch

Tags: php, foreach

Нужно из базы загнать данные в `switch` и оставить всё это в виде функции для дальнейшего использования

```
function cat($id) {
    switch ($id) {
        foreach( $array as $key => $value ){
            case $key: return $value; break;
        }
    }
}
```

Бред конечно, но как сделать?

Comment: А `switch`-то тут зачем? Если я правильно понял, то у вас получается: `function cat($id) { return $array[$id]; }`

Comment: Приведите пример со значениями

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Т.е. Ваша функция должна брать данное `$id`, искать такой же `$key` и возвращать соответствующее `$value`?

Тогда вам нужна `array_key_exists()` функция.
Что-то типа такого.

```
function cat($id) {
    if (!array_key_exists($id, $array)) return false;
    return $array[$id];
}
```

Comment: Кстати интересный вот вопрос:

С foreach работать внутри функции и вызывать в switch именно ее. Насколько разумно с вашей точки зрения?

Comment: @DisguisePerceptron насколько я знаю такой способ, как предложил автор, работать не должен. Должна ошибка парсинга вылезать. Вобщем думаю, что совсем не разумно...

Answer (score 2):

Если немного проанализировать алгоритм, то можно сконфигурировать код **foreach** таким образом, что он заменит функционал **switch**:

```
/* (c) red_python@ru.stackoverflow.com */
/*         Foreach into Switch         */
$arr = // Your array
[
  'a' => '123',
  'b' => '567',
  'c' => '890',
];


$test = 'b';

switch ($test) // switch ($test)  ===>  if ($test == $k)
{
  case 'a': echo '123'; break; // case 'x': echo '000'; break;
  case 'b': echo '567'; break; //// case  $k: echo  arr[$k]; break;
  case 'b': echo '567'; break; ///// echo $arr[$k]
  default : break;
}

// remastered from SWITCH to FOREACH

foreach ($arr as $k => $v)
  {
    if ($test == $k) echo $arr[$k];
  }
```